# How can i link a video in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, video

My video is not appearing in each Video element, is there anything wrong with my codes? can anyone help me? Thank you so much!

This is my Video.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Video.css";

function Video() {
  return (
    <div className="video">
      <video src="./video.mp4"> </video>{" "}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Video;
```

This is my App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Video from "./Video";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      hello code{" "}
      <div className="app">
        <div className="app-videos">
          <Video />
          <Video />
          <Video />
          <Video />
        </div>{" "}
      </div>{" "}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my App.css:

```
html {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.app {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

.app-videos {
    position: relative;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 500px;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
```

This is my Video.css:

```
.video {
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid red;
    background-color: white;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

This is my directory:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMn26.png)

Answer (score 2):

The video HTML tag has a children `<source/>`. That accepts the video URL in the `src` prop.

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls> 
<source src="./video.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
</video>
```

Refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Comment: @Babilon If this one answers your question then please consider accepting the answer. That'll conclude the question.

Comment: Thank you! It does display the video but why when i hit the play button the video is not playing tho?